# How to call a function of a controller from a view?

Tags: php, phalcon

There is a controller :

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;
class ReferentielClientController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction(){
        // moteur de template pour une View
        $this->view->act_form = 'ReferentielClient/ajouterClient';
        return $this->view->pick("client/listerClient");
    }

    public function ajouterClientAction(){
        $this->view->action_form = 'ajouterClientExec';
        return $this->view->pick("client/ajouterClient");
    }
    ...
}
```

From a `view` I want to call the `indexAction` method of the controller `ReferentielClientController`. How to do that ?

Comment: “From a view I want to call the `indexAction` method of the controller.” No, you don’t. A view is supposed to present data. The controller’s job is to fetch the data for presenting. You should _not_ be doing any calling of controllers actions (or model methods) in your views.

Comment: Man... Don't do that. Don't contradict MVC

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: You can't.

You can't since indexAction is not a normal method, it's an action. Actions aren't called by anyone in the usual way that methods are, they are called with routes an url. Let me explain this a little bit further:

Using [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), we have the following route using :
http://www.example.org/a/b/c

a is which we call module.
b is which we call controller.
And c is which we call action.

Index actions and default modules will not appear in the URL.

So, how to call functions from view? Better not to. Best way to proceed is to do everything in your controller and pass that info to the view. I.e.:

```
public function indexAction(){
    $this->view->myInfo = $allMyInformationInOneObject;
}
```

And then, in the view (index.phtml):

```
<p>
    <?php echo $this->myInfo ?>
</p>
```

Summary:
You don't need to call any controller function from the view, just give it that info from the controller.

### Added info about redirection

OK, answering to your commentary. What you want is not to call that function but to redirect the browser to that action.

So, I'll suppose you have your route created in your router, if not, please, go to the [Zend documentation about routing](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html). It's highly recommended to create routes instead of using the URL itself.

I guess that you will not be able to use the normal redirecting using *href* on a button or such, so you will need to use the *redirector* helper. Since you are not in a controller, you are not able to use the helper by using:

```
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrl($url);
```

So you will need to instance the *redirector* like this:

```
$redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
$redirector->gotoUrl($url);
```

Being this $url, the URL given by your router, as you can read in the link above.

This can be done but I strongly recommend not to redirect from the view but from the controller. It would be good that all the logic remains in the controller.

I hope this helps!

Comment: but I want a button to redirect the app to that action ; how to do that ?

Comment: I edit my answer adding new information about redirection :).

Comment: I don't use Zend ! I use Phalcon.

Comment: Meh, sorry, I misread it. You should be able to redirect from the controller as well: [Docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/es/latest/reference/response.html#making-redirections)
I don't really think that redirecting from the view is a good idea, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it : I set the `href` to point to the controller : `<a href="/resto/ReferentielClient" class="button default">Annuler</a>`